# Add Scroll View Controller between multiple view controllers scenes

Tags: ios, swift

Working on an IOS8 swift app, I'm looking for the way to include the scroll view controller between multiple view controller scenes, my app consists in:
one tab bar controller scene with three buttons(icons) linked to three view controller scenes. I can navigate between the three views using the tab bar buttons but I'd like to navigate between these three views implementing the scroll view controller. Anyone can suggest me please?

Comment: Let me get this straight.  You want to be able to scroll to navigate through view controllers in a tab bar controller?

Comment: No milesper, sorry, I want to navigate through view controllers scrolling horizontally the views, forget the tab bar controller.

Comment: But the scroll view contains the views?  Or does each view contain a scroll view?

Comment: the scroll view should contain the views

Comment: There is no such thing as a "scroll view controller". You can do this using a UIPageViewController using the scrolling transition between pages.

Comment: Au contraire, its just the code that manages the scroll view and subviews.  But good idea with the PageViewController

Comment: OK thanks, and is posible to add a UIpageViewController to a Tab bar Interface?